# Angular Datepicker with Range Selection like vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm using angular 10 and I wanted to implement a date picker like this: https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-js-date-range-picker-with-multiples-ranges-and-presets/ with week, month, and year range.

Do you know any libraries for my purpose? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following component with the help of `Angular Material` :

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate matInput placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate matInput placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

link to Stackblitz may help you more:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-date-picker-range-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.ts